# cannot join to master node using kubeadm join

Tags: kubernetes, centos

I am trying to set up a kubernetes cluster and running this command on my worker node
`kubeadm join server:port --token xxx  --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx`
and the error i have is

```
Found multiple CRI endpoints on the host. Please define which one do you wish to use by setting the 'criSocket' field in the kubeadm configuration file: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock, unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
```

I am not sure which container runtime to use here, so i modified the command as
`kubeadm join server:port --token xxx  --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxx --cri-socket /var/run/crio/crio.sock`
but the error is

```
[ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: I0617 21:55:27.908044 1877581 util_unix.go:103] "Using this endpoint is deprecated, please consider using full URL format" endpoint="/var/run/crio/crio.sock" URL="unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock"
E0617 21:55:27.908867 1877581 remote_runtime.go:616] "Status from runtime service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/crio/crio.sock: connect: no such file or directory\""
time="2023-06-17T21:55:27+05:30" level=fatal msg="getting status of runtime: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial unix /var/run/crio/crio.sock: connect: no such file or directory\""
, error: exit status 1
```

Can someone suggest the correct approach here

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. I am voting to close this question.

Comment: Refer to this [doc](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/crio/crio_runtime.html) helpful to resolve your error

Answer (score 1):

`cri-socket` is which container runtime in the host you want to use.

- If there is only one of `cri-o``cri-dockerd`\`containerd`, it will auto detect and choose it for you.
- In your case, there are two: `cri-dockerd` and `containerd`. So kubeadm cannot decide which to use. You should make a decision.
- If you don't want either cri-docker for docker or containerd.sock for containerd, you should install [cri-o](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o) before using it.